# Getting Access denied error while installing phpmyadmin in ubuntu11.4

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-11.04

Im a newbie in ubuntu. Im getting an error while installing phpmyadmin in ubuntu11.4 server. It says

```
An error occurred while installing the database:
ERROR 1045 (28000):Access denaid for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password:YES);
```

I am sure that I used the correct password for root. I can login to mysql through putty.
Do I need to do anything with privileges?

Please help me to sort this issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest:

```
mysql -h localhost -u root -p
```

and you typed something else. :(

`pidof mysqld` says what exactly? If nothing then `sudo service mysql start` and try

```
mysql -h localhost -u root -p
```

again.

Re-configure mysql-server:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server
```

or

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.1
```

whichever one is installed.

Once you reconfigure (and recover) your root mysql password, then
Reconfigure phpmyadmin

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin
```

Answer (score 0):

i ran into the same issue and just figured my problem. I used an "ü" in my Root user's password. It seems like PHPMYADMIN can't handle the utf-8 set. So I altered the password to "abc" and it worked! Just dont forget to undo your temporary password :)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and installed my machine again, because I though I did something wrong. But same problem after re-installation of Ubuntu.

What works for me is to install mysql-server and phpmyadmin NOT as root user. I create a new user `adduser admin` and put them into the sudo group with `adduser admin sudo`. After that, I exit my ssh-connection with the root-account and login with the new admin-user. Now, I install both software-bundles and, suprise, all works fine.